CSRF token mismatch on Laravel 11 and React 18 Axios.post
CSRF token mismatch on Laravel 11 and React 18 Axios.post but not in Axios.get.
What to do?

Hello! Are you using Laravel sanctum and React as SPA?

Yes I am using that.

I got it now to work by reading Laravel Sanctum Documentation.

From the sanctum documentation:
To authenticate your SPA, your SPA's "login" page should first make a request to the /sanctum/csrf-cookie endpoint to initialize CSRF protection for the application:
axios.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie').then(response => {
    // Login...
});


Thanks but I got it to work with an another way like configuring cross domain with multiple ways. But I am not happy with my configuration because my App is Atlassian Jira Cloud Connect App and now it works only for one cross domain and I need to get it wot work dynamically for multiple domains *.alassian,net.
